# Proper way to handle "check list" of items

Tags: java, oop, data-structures

I have a process that must complete a set of tasks. It is possible that the process will try attempt a task that has already been completed, in which case it should ignore the attempt and generate a request to complete another task. I am not sure of a good way to track which tasks are completed and which still need to be processed.

I will use the game "Yahtzee" as an example to demonstrate how I am currently handling this. I first create the list of tasks, in this case the scoring combinations:

```
combinations = new ArrayList<String>();
combinations.add("one");
combinations.add("two");
...
combinations.add("fullhouse");
combinations.add("smallstraight");
combinations.add("yahtzee");
...
```

When the player uses one of these combinations, I remove it from the arraylist, in this case the "small straight" combination:

```
public void selectSmallStraight() {
    int index = combinations.indexOf("smallstraight");
    if(index < 0)
        System.out.println("Small Straight already used");
        //Prompt the player for another selection
    else
        combinations.remove(index);
        score += 30;
}
```

Once all of the combinations have been used, the game ends.

Using an array list seems very primitive to me, not to mention ugly. I have considered using a `Map<String, Boolean>` and then just marking the object as false once it has been used, but I would assume there is already some "standard" way of doing this much more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arraylist example may be a bit inefficient for what you're doing, and it has the possibility of accidentally mistyping an action. If you have a set number of actions, why not keep them in a boolean array?

```
final static int FIRSTACTION = 0;
final static int SECONDACTION = 1;
final static int LASTACTION = 2;
boolean[] actionsFinished = new boolean[3];
```

Then you can set it after finishing:

```
//Do first action code goes here
actionsFinished[FIRSTACTION] = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

If a primitive solution works, then that's often the best solution. Why make it more complicated?

The only disadvantage I can see with using just an `ArrayList` is that searching in it is slow. Using a `Map` for this would be better.

But it may be even better if you created a class that knows whether it was already used and put that into a map.

Comment: The main issue I have with the ArrayList approach is performance, just like you stated.

Comment: @Kededro So a HashSet which relies on a HashMap would do the job